# Delphi 2010 - ADODataSet - SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM MTR

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I am rework the Delphi project from the Access database to the MS SQL 2008 database.

The old string of CommandText in ADODataSet looked

```
SELECT SUM (Cost) FROM MTR
```

It does not work with the new database. Error "Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator."

I searched the network for various options, but all lead to one - "Error converting varchar data type to float."
For instance:

```
SELECT SUM (Cost) FROM (SELECT CAST (REPLACE ('Cost', 'NULL', '0') AS FLOAT) AS Cost) AS MTR
```

I really hope for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like column `Cost` in table `MTR` has got wrong type in your MSSQL database. It should be `FLOAT`, `DECIMAL`, `MONEY`, or other numeric type rather then `nvarchar` (probably this is result of automatic DB schema conversion from Access to MSSQL). 
Once you will change column type, original SQL `SELECT SUM (Cost) FROM MTR` will work.

Comment: If I change the field type to Float, I get an error in Delphi "MTP: Type mismatch for field 'Cost', expecting: WideString actual: Float."

Comment: Check whether your ADODataSet has got Fields populated. You will need to clear Fields and either populate them again from real table (field will have correct type) or leave Fields empty and they will be populated when DataSet is open.

Comment: Thank you, very much! Need to clear Fields and either populate them again in ADOTable  and ADODataSet from real table (field will have correct type).